# Поиск подстроки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть список внутри которого есть ссылки, необходимо по клику по блоку #block получить его значение и сравнить его со значениями которые есть в ссылках, если произошло совпадение показать скрытый блок js-special-message, иначе его спрятать

```js
$('#block').on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var arrLink      = $("ul").find("a"),
        arrCurCity  = [],
        checkWord   = $(this).find("div").text();

    $.each(arrLink, function(i, e){
        arrCurCity.push( $(e).text() );
    })

    altasib_geobase.sc_add_city(event);

    $.each(arrCurCity, function(i, e){
        console.log(checkWord, e);
        if(checkWord.match( new RegExp(e, 'i') ) ){
            $(".js-special-message").hide();
        }
        if(!checkWord.match( new RegExp(e, 'i') ) ){
            $(".js-special-message").show();
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Пермь</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Москва</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Брянск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тула</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Калуга</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Смоленск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Орёл</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Белгород</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Воронеж</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Курск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Рязань</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тамбов</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Липецк</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Иваново</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Владимир</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ярославль</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="block">Липецкб Липецкая область</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#block').on("click",function(){
  const $this = $(this),
    thisText = $this.text(),
    $cityLink = $('ul a');
      
  $cityLink.each(function(){
    if(thisText === $(this).text()) {
      $('#js-special-message').show();
    } else {
      $('#js-special-message').hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Пермь</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Москва</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Брянск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тула</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Калуга</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Смоленск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Орёл</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Белгород</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Воронеж</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Курск</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Рязань</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тамбов</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Липецк</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Иваново</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Владимир</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ярославль</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="block">Липецкб Липецкая область</div>
<div id="js-special-message"></div>
```

Comment: ваш вариант не подходит потому что сам блок id="block" может содержать большое кол-во текста, поэтому надо проверять не на точное совпадение, а делать поиск подстроки

Comment: @кверти, используй тогда IndexOf вместо `==`

Answer (score -1):

Возможно такое решение подойдёт https://jsbin.com/fivihirato/edit?html,css,js,output

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Пермь</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Москва</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Брянск</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Тула</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Калуга</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Смоленск</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Орёл</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Белгород</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Воронеж</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Курск</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Рязань</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Тамбов</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Липецк</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Иваново</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Владимир</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ярославль</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="block">Липецкб Липецкая область</div>
    <div id="js-special-message">Супер-сообщение</div>
```

css:

```
#js-special-message{
  display: none;
}

#block{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

js:

```
var $message = $('#js-special-message');
$('#block').on('click', function(e){
    //из объекта события извлекаем текст из элемента 
    //на котором возникло событие (target), то есть из блока
    var text = e.target.innerText;
    //проходим по элементам списка
    $('ul li').each(function(index, elem){
      //извлекаем текст из элемента списка
      var linkText = elem.innerText;
      //на его основе формируем регулярку c флагом 'i'
      //для проверки без учёта регистра
      var re = new RegExp(linkText, 'i');
        //сопоставляем текст из блока с регуляркой
        if(text.match(re)){
            //если сопоставление сработало:
            //показываем сообщение и покидаем цикл с помощью return false
            $message.show();
            return false;
        } else {
            //иначе скрываем сообщение
            $message.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Стоит помимо ссылки оставлять код решения, т.к. ссылка может быть в последствии удалена.

Comment: если используешь регулярки, зачем приводит текст к нижнему регистру?

Comment: осталось только ключ `i` в регулярку добавить

Comment: и добавь пояснение, что и как делает твой код